# Changing pages of a website hosted in WebKit from iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using Swift 3 with WebKit to create an app for iOS that is running off of HTML, CSS, and JS. My problem is that when I am clicking a link on the page to change to a different HTML file, nothing happens. Here is my code for my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let page = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "HTML/index", ofType: "html")!
        var content: String?
        do {
            content = try String(contentsOfFile: page, encoding: 
String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }

        let base = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "HTML/main", ofType: "css")!
        let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: base)
        webView.loadHTMLString(content!, baseURL: baseUrl)
    }
}
```

and here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Opus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a class="activeNav" href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="/settings.html">Settings</a>
        <a href="https://opus.com/help" target="_blank">Help</a>
    </div>
    <span onclick="openNav()">&#124;&#124;&#124;</span>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header"> Opus </div>
        <img src="google.png">
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add the index.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<a href="/settings.html">Settings</a>` is the link you are trying to click, in a hosted webpage the href resolves to `<domain>/settings.html`. But since this is all local, there is no domain, it would not get resolved properly. However the complete path doesn't work either, because in a simulator giving a macOS path will complain that it cannot load the local file, and in a phone it would not even have access to the file. What you should do is pass this message along to the native code using javascript bridge and `WKScriptMessageHandler` and let the native part handle loading the `settings.html` page. For example:

```
func viewDidLoad{
  ....
  weak var weakSelf = self //To avoid leaking memory
  self.webView.configuration.userContentController.add(weakSelf, name: "MyMessageHandler")
 ...
}
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
   if message.name == "MyMessageHandler"{
      if message.body == "openSettings",let settingsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HTML/settings", withExtension: "html"){
         self.webView.load(URLRequest(url:settingsURL)) //You can load it the way you did it in your question if you want css too.
      }
   }
}
```

And in your index.html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openSettings()">Settings</a>
<script>
func openSettings(){
   window.webkit.messageHandlers.MyMessageHandler.postMessage("openSettings");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are right, I changed /settings.html to settings.html and it now works fine. Thanks again!